# Getting OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory while downloading Android source code

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to download http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html.
According to the instruction writing in terminal this command:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

and I am getting the next error:

```
comrade@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/comrade/bin/repo", line 700, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/comrade/bin/repo", line 667, in main
    _Init(args)
  File "/home/comrade/bin/repo", line 198, in _Init
    _CheckGitVersion()
  File "/home/comrade/bin/repo", line 223, in _CheckGitVersion
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am novice in Ubuntu and so I am sorry if question is dull.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is solved.
I had not a git client.**